# Drag images smooth on mobile devices with javascript

Tags: javascript, hardware-acceleration

Hi i want to create a javascript application where i have to drag images around. I've broken it down to the minimum here (works only for touch events, needs jquery):

```js
  var draggable = $("#draggable")[0];
  draggable.x = 0;
  draggable.y = 0;

  $("#draggable").bind('touchstart', function(e) {
    draggable.lastmouse = e.originalEvent.touches[0];

  });
  $("#draggable").bind('touchmove', function(f) {
    f = f.originalEvent.touches[0];
    var newx = draggable.x + (f.clientX - draggable.lastmouse.clientX);
    var newy = draggable.y + (f.clientY - draggable.lastmouse.clientY);
    draggable.x = newx;
    draggable.y = newy;
    $(draggable).css('transform', 'translate3d(' + newx + 'px,' + newy + 'px,0)');
    draggable.lastmouse = f;
  });
```

```html
<div class="map" id="draggable" style="width: 90%; height: 90%; position: absolute;">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/FuBK-Testbild.png" width="100%" height="100%">
</div>
```

On a Computer it runs smooth, but on my GalaxyS4 its stuttering when i drag the image around, although i used translate3d. I thought it would be hardware accellerated.

Is there a way to get a native-app-like performance?

Comment: If you can drag Google map smoothly on your device, than I guess it is possible, question is how.... Have you tried [this plugin](http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-kinetic-smooth-drag-scrolling) and maybe [this one](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm now going with HTML5 canvas, its performance is much better than my old approach and my code is much more intuitive